# Accessing Plague Wing of Naxxramas

Tags: hearthstone

I tried to buy the Plague Wing of Naxxramas with gold.
But I'm stuck at an endless "Waiting for Authorization" screen.

I understand that a lot of people are seeing this (but I can't read posts cause I'm behind a work web filter.)
Was anyone able to get past this Authorization Screen without losing their gold?

UPDATE:
Well I just left it sitting there "Waiting for Authorization" and eventually it logged me out cause I had been inactive for too long.

Comment: The shop is closed for me so I guess there's an issue they're fixing.

Comment: @3ventic Are you in the US?

Comment: No, I'm in EU..

Comment: EU shop got back online,for me atleast few minutes ago.

Comment: @Arremer if you dare purchase with gold, let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after restarting Hearthstone I had been charged exactly 700 Gold and the Plague Wing was unlocked.

I'm still unclear if I could have done that at any time. If anyone can answer with more precision I will accept that answer.

Hopefully we won't be back here next wing, but if we are, I'll try to post updates here.

Comment: Purchased the Military Wing this morning at 6AMEST. First click on "buy" immediately popped up a "Purchase Complete" Message Box without deducting gold _or_ opening the wing. I restarted Hearthstone, the Military Wing still had a "buy" button so I clicked it again. This time it let me choose to pay with gold, deducted 700 gold, and opened the wing.

Comment: Purchased the Construct Wing this morning at 6AMEST. No problems at all purchasing with gold.

Answer (score 3):

The shop got overloaded when everybody tried to buy it at midnight. It's been going up and down throughout the day.

Real money purchases are fine- at least I haven't seen anyone complaining- because the real money purchasing system is so much more robust. This is understandable- charging someone real money twice would result in a lot of hassle and potentially legal action whereas Blizz can do whatever they want with Gold.

Gold purchases are still glitchy at the moment, judging by the forums. You're probably better off waiting.

Comment: Also when you pay something with real money it will go through your credit card and you will have the receipt whether or not you receive anything,so you can always contact the customer support if it doesn't appear later on.

Comment: That answer is helpful for folks who have yet to buy... but since waiting is something that I already didn't do, it doesn't really help me.